# Universal App Resource resw values in different views

Tags: localization, uwp

I try to create a Universal Windows App which has a main window containing different views.

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SimplePage));
```

where `ContentFrame` is a XAML Frame and `SimplePage` is a view.

The project has two localisations. Therefore I created a folder `Strings` in the solution containing two folders, `en` and `de`, containing each a `Resources.resw` file.

I want to use a string from the `resw`-file inside the SimplePage-view. Therefore I tried:

```
tbSimpleInput1.Text = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetValue("Resources/dataToolDiameter", ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView()).ValueAsString;
```

I also tried using `ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse()` instead of `ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView()` but I always get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to debug.

What is the correct way to access the resources in different views?

Here a screenshot of the solution in Visual Studio:

[image: Solution]

Comment: Do you have "dataToolDiameter" in your resource file? If you're having Germany for your locale settings, you need to search Resources file under de folder.

Comment: Yes, the resource is defined correctly. When I use the same statement in the main window it works, only if I want to use it in the sub-view I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having a single-project solution, I'd recommend you either to create a `Shell` - as the Microsoft example recommends, or to use the `App.xaml.cs` class for localization purposes.

First, in the constructor of either class, get the current `ResourceLoader`:

```cs
// E.g use the static constructor of your App class
static App()
{
    _resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
}
```

Now getting a resource (e.g. a text) is very easy:

```cs
public static string GetLocalizedString(string key)
{
    return _resourceLoader.GetString(key);
}
```

Now you can load a string form the default resource dictionary:

```cs
tbSimpleInput1.Text = App.GetLocalizedString("dataToolDiameter");
```

Please note: this only works as long as you use the default pattern for localization in your project. If you use different resource files, you'd have use an overload of the `ResourceLoader` constructor.

Comment: Could you please give me a link to the Microsoft example? I wasn't able to find it.
Does the `App()` has to be `static`? By default it is public and if I change it to static i get errors.

Comment: @daengl The example is part a MVA video. You can find it by looking into the starter guide of Universal Windows Apps there. You shall not change the class declaration, you have to introduce a static constructor, as the code example (and the comment) in the answer suggest.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I didn't know anything about MVA yet.